# How to handle non-ascii character in http get parameter

Tags: rest, http, urlencode

In our express (with typescript) app, we are calling an external api and normally we would send a http GET using `axios` like
`foo/api/search/hello world` where `hello world` is entered by the user of a web app. We call `encodeURIComponent` on the parameter so we will send `foo/api/search/hello%20world` to the external api. And this works fine until someone tried to enter something that is non-ascii, s.a. `hello tânia`; this causes us to send `foo/api/search/hello%20t%C3%A2nia` to the external api and we got a http 400 back.

Is this something that the external api should handle or we shall handle it on our side?
Either way, how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

So in general the **encodeURIComponent()** function encodes all special characters into their matching UTF-8 encoding, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). So your client is doing everything right, but it seems like your server which is receiving the HTTP GET is for some reason not capable of correctly handling the UTF-8 encoded URI.

Comment: Guess the server is not decoding it properly then?